# Scala - Vector.tabulate and structural sharing

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I have a value representing a chess board

```
val board: Vector[Vector[Option[Piece]]] = ...
```

and in some function to apply moves I construct a new board from this one using tabulate

```
Vector.tabulate(8,8)(
  (x,y) => 
    if (x,y) == (start_x,start_y)
      None
    else if (x,y) == (end_x,end_y)
      board(start_x)(start_y)
    else
      board(x)(y)
)
```

Would the memory usage of this snippet be constant, since only two cells are changed? In other words, is the data reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will be no structural sharing between the new board and the old board. If you throw the old board way after this snippet, memory will be constant, but it would be more efficient to use as much of the old board as possible. Try:

```
val piece = board(start_x)(start_y)
val board2 = board.updated(start_x, board(start_x).updated(start_y, None))
val newboard = board2.updated(end_x, board2(end_x).updated(end_y, piece))
```

Comment: Thank you! When you say it is more efficient this way, is that because you don't have to spend time copying the cells of the board?

Comment: There's that, but I was thinking in terms of memory usage. `newboard` reuses most of the subvectors from board, for at least all but two of the rows. Also, using `updated` may return a `Vector` that reuses many of the pieces of the previous `Vector`. It's similar to doing `x :: list.tail` to get a new list that shares most of its structure with the old list.